# Group by client a list of random invoices

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of random invoices and each invoice has its own client.

I want to group my invoices by client.

I have this :

```
$randomInvoices = [
    [
     "name" => "studio",
     "client_id" => 111,
     "invoice" => 1233,
     "email" => 'studio@studio.com.br'
    ],
    [
     "name" => "italiano",
     "client_id" => 222,
     "invoice" =>  6775,
     "email" => 'italiano@italia.com'
    ],
    [
     "name" => "studio",
     "client_id" => 111,
     "invoice" => 577,
     "email" => 'studio@studio.com.br'
    ],
    [
     "name" => "italiano",
     "client_id" => 222,
     "invoice" =>  677543,
     "email" => 'italiano@italia.com'
    ],

];
```

I want this :

```
$invoicesByClient = [
    [
     "client_id" => 111,
     "name" => "studio",
     "invoices" => [1233, 577]
     "email" => 'studio@studio.com.br'
    ],
    [
     "client_id" => 222,
     "name" => "italiano",
     "invoices" => [6775, 677543],
     "email" => 'italiano@italia.com'
    ],

];
```

How do I achieve this result in the simplest way? I tried a bunch of foreachs but it got too confusing.

```
function getValueByTrigger($array, $triggerKey, $triggerValue, $returnKey) {
$invoices = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if($item[$triggerKey] == $triggerValue) {
            $invoices[] = $item[$returnKey];
        }
    }
    return $invoices;


foreach ($invoicesByClient as $key => $value) {
    $invoicesByClient[$key]['invoices'] = getValueByTrigger($randomInvoices, 'client_id', $value['client_id'], 'invoice');
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build you loop as:

```
$invoicesByClient = [];
foreach ($randomInvoices as $value) {
    $clientId = $value['client_id'];
    if (!isset($invoicesByClient[$clientId])) {
        $invoicesByClient[$clientId] = [
            "name" => $value['name'],
            "client_id" => $clientId,
            "email" => $value['email'],
            'invoices' => [],
        ];
    }
    $invoicesByClient[$clientId]['invoices'][] = $value['invoice'];
}
// use `array_values` to get 0-indexed array
$invoicesByClient = array_values($invoicesByClient);
```

Fiddle is [here](https://3v4l.org/OO1Ai).